# Get current request path but with a changed format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can use `request.fullpath` to get the relative path of the current request (or `request.path` to not include query parameters). In my case I want to redirect from PDF to HTML if PDF generation fails, so I want to get the corresponding path in a different format.

Obviously, I could do

```
request.fullpath.sub(".pdf", "")
```

but is there a more standard way? For one, the path may include `.pdf` somewhere inside. Of course, this possibility can be worked around, but this would complicate code.

Rails version is 6.1.

Comment: You don't actually need to redirect here. Even if the browser requested a PDF you can respond with a `text/html` content type and a HTML body that explains the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the URL of the current action is specified somewhere in `routes.rb` you can just use `redirect_to format: :html` or `redirect_to format: nil` to redirect you PDF request to the HTML one.

Also, if you need that HTML URL for something different from redirecting then you can get the URL using `url_for(format: :html)`.

And, if your original request had some query parameters you can try `redirect_to request.query_parameters.merge(format: :html)`